# Why passing integer to Mustache template causes error?

Tags: python, ruby, mustache

In [Mustache template](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) I have:

```
params = {
   "a": rand(20)
}
```

and this template:

```
exercise = {
   "solution": params[:a] + 1
}
```

I want to render but neither [Ruby](https://github.com/mustache/mustache) nor [Python](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron) does:

- Ruby

  ```
  puts Mustache.render(exercise[:solution], params)
  ```

  Error:

  > no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)
- Python

  ```
  print(chevron.render(template=exercise["solution"], data=params))
  ```

  Error:

  > AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

A workaround is cast integer to string:

- `str(params["a"] + 1)` in Python.
- `(params[:a] + 1).to_s` in Ruby.

Why does my code not work?

Comment: I don't see a template. I only see Hashes

Comment: Besides the template you want to render, please also add any error messages or unexpected behavior you see. Please edit your question and add this information to your initial question.

Comment: @HolgerJust I did not include error messages because I did not want to mess the question.

Comment: @engineersmnky The template is `exercise[:solution]` as you can see in the function call in ruby (in python, `exercise["solution"]`). I think it really does not matter if a template string is in a hash or in a class or something else. The behaviour is what I want to solve. Not the structure.

Comment: @somenxavier `exercise[:solution]` is not a template which was what my comment was about.

Comment: *"I think it really does not matter if a template string..."* actually it does matter very much for instance change `exercise = {"solution": params[:a] + 1}` to `exercise = "solution: {{a + 1}}"` and then try `Mustache.render(exercise, params)`. **Hint:** This error "no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)" is because `excercise[:solution]` is the result of `rand(20) + 1`. e.g. assume `rand(20) == 10` you are calling the render as  `Mustache.render(11, {a: 10})`. The first Integer `11` is what is causing your error becuase a mustache template needs to be a String.